# Keep getting 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable' with beautiful soup and python3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, typeerror, nonetype

I am a beginner and struggling though a course, so this problem is probably really simple, but I am running this (admittedly messy) code (saved under file x.py) to extract a link and a name from a website with line formats like:

```html
<li style="margin-top: 21px;">
  <a href="http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Prabhjoit.html">Prabhjoit</a>
</li>
```

So I set up this:
    import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import ssl
    # Ignore SSL certificate errors
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

```
url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for line in soup:
    if not line.startswith('<li'):
        continue
    stuff = line.split('"')
    link = stuff[3]
    thing = stuff[4].split('<')
    name = thing[0].split('>')
    count = count + 1
    if count == 18:
        break
print(name[1])
print(link)
```

And it keeps producing the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 15, in <module>
    if not line.startswith('<li'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I have struggled with this for hours, and I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using *code to split text* on BeautifulSoup elements. Please, do [read the library documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), you'll find that the API offered is very different from what you are using here.

Comment: If you want to use `startswith` then convert into string first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line` is not a string, and it has no `startswith()` method. It is a [*BeautifulSoup `Tag` object*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag), because BeautifulSoup has parsed the HTML source text into a rich object model. Don't try to treat it as text!

The error is caused because if you access any attribute on a `Tag` object that it doesn't know about, it does a [*search for a child element with that name*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names)  (so here it executes `line.find('startswith')`), and since there is no element with that name, `None` is returned. `None.startswith()` then fails with the error you see.

If you wanted to find the 18th `<li>` element, just ask BeautifulSoup for that specific element:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
li_link_elements = soup.select('li a[href]', limit=18)
if len(li_link_elements) == 18:
    last = li_link_elements[-1]
    print(last.get_text())
    print(last['href'])
```

This uses a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to find only the `<a>` link elements whose parent is a `<li>` element and that have a `href` attribute. The search is limited to just 18 such tags, and the last one is printed, but only if we actually found 18 in the page.

The element text is retrieved with the [`Element.get_text()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text), which will include text from any nested elements (such as `<span>` or `<strong>` or other extra markup), and the `href` attribute is [accessed using standard indexing notation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes).